# How to view PDF doc from Firebase storage in React using react-pdf?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, pdf, react-pdf

I would like to view a pdf file from firebase storage in my React app, the problem is I would like to view the file after the page is loaded and the 'getDownloadURL' firebase method is async.

I tried  to do something like this:

```
    const MyPage = (props) => {
      const [numPages, setNumPages] = useState(null)
      const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1)
      const [url, setURL] = useState('')
    
     const showFile = async () => {
        return await storage.ref(props.props.sheetMusicRef).getDownloadURL()
      }
    
    return   <Document file={showFile}>
              <Page pageNumber={pageNumber} />
            </Document>
}
```

with no success.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar today, where I wanted to simply fetch a pdf from Firebase Storage, show a loader in the meantime, and render the file. I decided to not go for react-pdf for my own use case, as I wanted to embed the file over the whole viewport. Skip to the next header if you want to see my proposed solution to your code specifically.

### My solution

This component fetches the pdf from Firebase Storage, before embedding the file over the whole viewport. For making sure that I do not get the ability to scroll over or under, mimicing the behavior of opening a file straight in the browser, I utilize the "body-scroll-lock"-package from npm. I also use MUI for styled components. So, if you anyone comes onto this post and want a working full screen pdf-viewer, fetching the pdf from Firebase Storage and showing a loader, here you go:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Box, Typography, useMediaQuery } from "@mui/material";
import { FC, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useTheme } from "../ThemeProvider";
import { disableBodyScroll, clearAllBodyScrollLocks } from "body-scroll-lock";
import { Seek } from "react-loading-indicators";
import { getDownloadURL, ref } from "firebase/storage";
import { storage } from "../firebaseConfig";

const LandingPage: FC = (props) => {
  const targetRef = React.createRef();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [pdf, setPdf] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    disableBodyScroll(targetRef);

    getDownloadURL(ref(storage, "firebase_storage_path.pdf"))
      .then((url) => {
        setPdf(url);
        setInterval(() => setIsLoading(false), 500);
      })
      .catch(() => setIsLoading(false));

    return () => {
      clearAllBodyScrollLocks();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
     <Box
     ref={targetRef}
     display="flex"
     justifyContent="center"
     alignItems="center"
     sx={{
       height: "100vh",
       width: "100vw",
     }}
   >
     {isLoading ? (
       <Seek color="#000" size="small" />
     ) : !pdf ? (
       <Typography variant="h4">Oops, something went wrong</Typography>
     ) : (
       <embed type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%" src={pdf} />
     )}
   </Box>
  );
};
export default LandingPage;
```

### The solution to your problem specifically

I have modified the code you have provided, and proposed some changes that would work the way you want it to. This shows a loader while fetching the file, fetches the file from Firebase Storage, and shows either an error message if something went wrong, or loads the pdf using react-pdf.

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import React from "react";
import { Seek } from "react-loading-indicators";
import { getDownloadURL, ref } from "firebase/storage";
import { storage } from "../firebaseConfig";
import { Document, Page } from "react-pdf";

const MyPage = (props) => {
  const [numPages, setNumPages] = useState(null);
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [url, setURL] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    getDownloadURL(ref(storage, "firebase_storage_path.pdf"))
      .then((url) => {
        setURL(url);
        // Could include a way of updating numPages here
        setInterval(() => setIsLoading(false), 500); // Just for the sake of showing the loader
      })
      .catch(() => setIsLoading(false));

    return () => {};
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) return <Seek color="#000" size="small" />; // Show loader
  else {
    if (!url)
      return <p>Oops, something went wrong</p>; // If catched error from fetch
    else
      return (
        <Document file={url}>
          <Page pageNumber={pageNumber} />
        </Document>
        // Could also include a way of switching page number based on numPages
      );
  }
};
export default MyPage;
```